# Views: changing the language for taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

Is there a way to display taxonomy terms in a language given by a Views argument, i.e. to override the user's language preference? The field formatter "Plain text (localized)" doesn't do the trick.

Example:

**Tab one: English**

- Africa

  - Story 1
  - Story 2
- Middle East
- Europe

**Tab two: Français**

- Afrique

  - Histoire 1
- Moyen-Orient

  - Histoire 2
- Europe

The stories are a single content type, but completely different pieces of content (not translations). I'm using quicktabs to render this.

Edit: the taxonomy terms are already translated via the i18n module, the question is about getting Views to display the translation I want.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am in the exact same situation. My terms are translated but can't display them in the users' current language in Views

Answer (score 3):

By default views doesn't allow to filter the taxonomy terms by the language, only with nodes.

But, you can use the Internationalization Views:

http://drupal.org/project/i18nviews

After you enable the module go to relationships and add "Content: Taxonomy terms on node"
Then you can find " Taxonomy term: Language " under filters. This should do the trick.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! The module is a dev version, so I'll need some time to test this before accepting your answer.

Comment: Regardless being in dev, the alternative is to write a module and implement a call to _views_query_alter

Answer (score 0):

You can translate taxonomy terms with the [Internationalization module](http://drupal.org/project/i18n).

Comment: I have already done that. Editing the question to clarify.